# integer expected error...blank line?

Tags: bash, if-statement, integer

I'm getting a "integer expression expected error" when doing the following:

```
NM=$(<file)
if test $NM -gt 0 
then
echo "workflow 1 would follow here"
else
if test $NM -lt 0
then
echo "workflow 2 would go after this"
else
echo "something else"
fi
fi
```

The file from which I am getting $NM assigned only contains one number (always an integer). This file is the output of a gmtmath operation.
I've noticed that if I open that file it has an extra line below the line containing the number and, if I manually delete that empty line my loop works and I don't get the error. However, I've tried to use sed in various ways to automatically delete empty lines and it deletes the entire content of the file, including the number. Any ideas??

Comment: That's a bit strange. Can you add the output of `echo -n "$NM" | hexdump -C` just after it is read?

Comment: I'm curious what loop you are talking about.  Is there a loop, or are you calling your conditional statements a loop?

Comment: I finally was able to reproduce and figure out your issue.  The answer is below, please remember to select an answer once your issue is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading some comments, I'm wondering if you are getting some unprintable characters.  I've tested this by putting in a \r before the \n, was finally able to  reproduce.  Here's a cleaned up version of your code, using tr to remove some extra characters.

```
NM=$(tr -cd '[:graph:]' <file)

if [[ $NM -gt 0 ]]; then
   echo "workflow 1 would follow here"
elif [[ $NM -lt 0 ]]; then
   echo "workflow 2 would go after this"
else
   echo "something else"
fi
```

I could have used other classes other than [:graph:].  I just end up using [:graph:] often, but to each their own.

Comment: `$(< file)` is the same as (and faster than) `$(cat file)`, see the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution).

Comment: I see-- my error was my test file had a hexdump already in it, so I thought it worked like `exec 3>$file'

Comment: That has solved it thanks! Bit of a newby I must admit, I would have never thought of using tr

Answer (score 0):

You want to test `${#NM}` is greater than zero (e.g. the number of characters in `$NM`). Currently you are testing the contents of the string against `0` and bash is telling you it needs a number. The same applies for each of your tests where you need a number.

If you want to test whether the word `"$NM"` is greater than `0` or less than `0` use `if ((NM > 0)); then ...` or `if ((NM < 0)); then ...`.

You can also use the older `test` expression `if [ "$NM" -gt 0 ]; then...` or `if test "$NM" -gt 0 ; then...` just be aware you will generate your error if `"$NM"` cannot be interpreted as a number. (you can redirect `stderr` to avoid that, but that isn't wise here).

Comment: He's also not loading the contents of the file, which is what he references later in his post.

Comment: Yes, I saw that and added the second set of tests.